# Throwing same exception inside catch block

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have following 2 code snippets and I am wondering what makes java compiler (In Eclipse with Java 7) to show error for 2nd snippet and why not for 1st one.

Here are the code snippets:

**snippet 1**

```
public class TestTryCatch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(get());
    }

    public static int get(){
        try{
            System.out.println("In try...");
            throw new Exception("SampleException");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("In catch...");
            throw new Exception("NewException");
        }
        finally{
            System.out.println("In finally...");
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

**snippet 2**

```
public class TestTryCatch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(get());
    }

    public static int get(){
        try{
            System.out.println("In try...");
            throw new Exception("SampleException");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("In catch...");
            throw new Exception("NewException");
        }
//      finally{
//          System.out.println("In finally...");
//          return 2;
//      }
    }
}
```

In eclipse, snippet1 shows to add 'SuppressWarning' for finally block, but in snippet2, it shows to add 'throws or try-catch' block for the **throw** statement in catch block.

I had a detailed look at following questions, but they didn't provide any concrete reason for this.

- [exception-thrown-inside-catch-block-will-it-be-caught-again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143622/exception-thrown-inside-catch-block-will-it-be-caught-again)
- [re-throw-an-exception-inside-catch-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437927/re-throw-an-exception-inside-catch-block)
- [throwing-an-exception-in-catch-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559376/throwing-an-exception-in-catch-block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `finally` block should *always* execute. This is the main reason. The exception is thrown in the `catch` block but `return` statement executed in the `finally` block masks exception. Either remove `finally` block or move `return` statement out of the `finally` block.

Comment: Thanks. So, its all about masking. We can say that, finally block will always masks the exception being thrown in catch block. Or, there are some criteria's for this as well.

Comment: @nipkon Then considering following block, each time we run this block the sequence of sysout's and stack trace in output is different.
`try{
   System.out.println("In try...");
   int x  = 10/0;
  }catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println("In catch...");
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally{
   System.out.println("In finally...");
  }`

Comment: sorry for above, couldn't make it look pretty in comments.

Answer (score 2):

In snippet 1, you don't need the return statement. In a finally block Java already know what to do once the finally block is treated: either continue an exception handling or jump to the next statement after the finally block.

So in snippet 1, simply move the return statement out of the finally block.

```
public static int get(){
    try {
        System.out.println("In try...");
        throw new Exception("SampleException");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("In catch...");
        throw new Exception("NewException");
    } finally{
        System.out.println("In finally...");
    }

    return 2;
}
```

In snippet 2, an exception is thrown in each block. Since this exception is not unchecked, it must be indicated in the method synopsis. Additionnally, there is no return statement and the return value of the method is not **void**.

Simply add a throws statement at the end of the method with a return statement.

```
public static void get() throws Exception {
    try{
        System.out.println("In try...");
        throw new Exception("SampleException");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("In catch...");
        throw new Exception("NewException");
    }
    //      finally{
    //          System.out.println("In finally...");
    //          return 2;
    //      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd snippet does not have a return value.  It has been commented out with the finally clause.

Try this

```
public static int get(){
    try{
        System.out.println("In try...");
        throw new Exception("SampleException");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("In catch...");
        throw new Exception("NewException");
    }
    return 2;   // must return a value
//      finally{
//          System.out.println("In finally...");
//          return 2;
//      }
```

Comment: The return statement is unreachable. All blocks behind it raise an exception.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Thanks.